# Recurrence Relation of a flipped coin

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> A single coin is flipped $n$ times.  Each outcome is represented by a sequence of $n$ digits; each digit is an $H$ or a $T$.  a) Find a recurrence relation for the number of outcomes with at least two consecutive heads.  b) Find a recurrence relation for the number of outcomes with no two consecutive heads.

a) Not too sure

b)I am assuming that the recurrence relation for the number of outcomes with no two consecutive heads would be $a_{n-1} + $a_{n-2}.

Can someone please explain this to me in detail and what was your moment of thought while doing this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For a):

Let $a_n$ be the sequence of H and T.

The sequence can start with H or T. If it starts with T, then there are $a_{n-1}$ combinations. If it starts with H, and the second one is T, then there are $a_{n-2}$ combinations. If the second one is H, then since it doesn't matter which ones the other ones are, there are $2^{n-2}$ combinations. Hence, $a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}+ 2^{n-2}$.

For b)

If $b_n$ is the sequence of H and T, notice that:

$b_n = 2^n - a_n$

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone please explain this to me in detail and what was your moment of thought while doing this problem?

The way I always start out working on these problems (finding a recurrence) is I consider the first coin, or the first object, or the first whatever it is.  It's not a foolproof rule, but it works very often.  So in this case, you want to start out considering the first coin and whether it is $H$ or $T$.  Then, if necessary, consider the second coin, the third coin, and so on.

For example, for (b), we could reason as follows:

- If the first coin is heads $H$, then the second coin *must* be $T$ to compensate.  After that, the coins could be anything with no two consecutive heads.  That is, the number of possibilities in this case is $b_{n-2}$.
- If the first coin is tails $T$, then the rest of the coins could be anything.  Therefore the number of possibilities in this case is $b_{n-1}$.

Over all, we have $b_n = b_{n-1} + b_{n-2}$.